# Consuming Blinktrade Rest API with python given error

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest

I'm new with python. Just few hours learning it.

I'm trying to consume an REST API to get some account infos...

Here is my request:

```
def getAccountData():
    nonce = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    signature = hmac.new(b'TDDh8djV3NwXt53gSrScDul6o6w3HnnZsHuh6HTF9SA', msg=nonce, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    print(signature)
    headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'APIKey':conf['API_KEY'],
            'Nonce':str(nonce),
        }
    data = {
            "MsgType": "U2",
            "BalanceReqID": 1
        }   
    r = requests.post('https://api.blinktrade.com/tapi/v1/message', data=data, headers=headers)
    print(r.json())
```

And here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "foxbit.py", line 51, in
>   
>       getAccountData()   File "foxbit.py", line 30, in getAccountData
>       signature = hmac.new(b'TDDh8djV3NwXt53gSrScDul6o6w3HnnZsHuh6HTF9SA', msg=nonce,
>   digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()   File
>   "C:\Python\Python35\lib\hmac.py", line 144, in new
>       return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)   File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\hmac.py", line 84, in **init**
>       self.update(msg)   File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\hmac.py", line 93, in update
>       self.inner.update(msg) TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

I'm trying consume this API:
`https://blinktrade.com/docs/?shell#balance`
on `balance` method

with no success.

I'm wanna create and python app to watch my opened orders of Bitcoin.
What was happening with this error?? On documentation, says i need do this to work:

```
{
    "MsgType": "U2",
    "BalanceReqID": 1
}
message='{ "MsgType": "U2", "BalanceReqID": 1 }'

api_url='API_URL_REST_ENDPOINT'
api_key='YOUR_API_KEY_GENERATED_IN_API_MODULE'
api_secret='YOUR_SECRET_KEY_GENERATED_IN_API_MODULE'

nonce=`date +%s`
signature=`echo -n "$nonce" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -hmac "$api_secret" | cut -d ' ' -f 2`

curl -X POST "$api_url"              \
  -H "APIKey:$api_key"               \
  -H "Nonce:$nonce"                  \
  -H "Signature:$signature"          \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d "$message"
```

3 hours trying it and nothing! hehe
I need some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not passing the nonce as a bytearray format when generating the signature.

This is a change after python 3.4

> hmac now accepts bytearray as well as bytes for the key argument to
>   the new() function, and the msg parameter to both the new() function
>   and the update() method now accepts any type supported by the hashlib
>   module. (Contributed by Jonas Borgström in bpo-18240.)

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#hmac

Passing a `bytearray` on nonce should work as expected.

```
signature = hmac.new(b'SECRET', msg=bytearray(nonce), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
```

Also, you are forgetting the `Signature` header.

You can follow this gist that has very useful python examples, it's actually built on python2, but you still can follow it, and it's very easy to get started.
https://gist.github.com/pinhopro/60b1fd213b36d576505e

As a BlinkTrade employee, don't hesite to ask me anything.